# CSS being cached somewhere, not locally, not on browser?

Tags: html, css, caching

My css appears to be being cached somewhere. I've uploaded a new css file and none of the changes have taken place. I thought that maybe it was being cached serverside so I slept on it and still, no updates to my css. I know it's not being cached in my browser because I've cleared that three times, and the tech support says server cannot cache. I need this css to take effect asap. Help would be much appreciated.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~Content/site.css?t123456789" type="text/css" />
```

is what I have in my head tag of my _layout page.

Comment: Did you update it to the correct server?  To the correct place on the server?  What happens when you browse to `http://myserver.com/csspath/theCssFile.css`?  If you were using a CDN you could have a problem with configuring the origin.

Comment: could you please post the new css that you have uploaded and also share the link of the live website..

Comment: have you checked the source code on server.?

Comment: Can you include your HTML file here that includes the `<link>` and the CSS file that includes the styles? It could be any number of issues; hard to say without more details.

Comment: Are you using something like Cloudflare? Is this a Wordpress site?

Comment: correct code on server, mvc site, code is correct. :/ this is why i've been banging my head against the table.

Comment: please post the css and the link to the website..

Comment: @SpencerDavis as mentioned by Lal, a link to the live site would be helpful

Comment: @Lal: I think we must be wary of getting into the habit of asking for a live site, since that renders the question (a) too localised and (b) only useful for the duration of the fault. There is a close vote specifically for posts that do not demonstrate a problem in a self-contained manner for this reason: if the only description and evidence of a fault will disappear when it is fixed, then the question probably is not suitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Spencer, try another browser, another computer or another connection?

Comment: Oh..sorry @halfer..was just thinking to solve the problem..what u said is correct and i truly appreciate that..thankyou

Answer (score 3):

You could try forcing the browser to refresh the css file by adding a timestamp to the link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path-to-your-css/styles.css?t=12345678910">
```

Comment: Even a random query string would suffice, to start off with, but yes, modification time is a good approach.